# An upper bound of a countable set of countable ordinals

Tags: ordinals

Let $X$ be a countable set of countable ordinals. Is there any upper bound of this set under $\omega_1$? In other words, can we find an ordinal $\alpha<\omega_1$ which is larger than any elements of $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** If $X$ is a set of ordinals, then $\bigcup X=\sup X$. If $X$ is a countable set of countable ordinals, then what is the cardinality of $\bigcup X$?

(You have to use the axiom of choice for this, though!)

Comment: Fairly certain you don't need Choice here. The countable union of countable sets isn't countable _in general_ without Choice, but that's because you need to order each of the sets (put them in 1-to-1 correspondence with $\omega$). Here, you can use the fact that they're well-ordered to define a good ordering, and you don't need Choice... I thought.

Comment: Yes, yes you need the axiom of choice here. $\omega_1$ is consistently singular without the axiom of choice. Meaning that it is the countable union of countable ordinals. Classical examples are the Feferman-Levy model and the Truss models for the perfect set property from a singular cardinal. Other models include Prikry forcing over models where $\omega_1$ is measurable (e.g. models of $\sf ZF+DC+AD$).

Comment: The point is that while the ordinals are uniformly well-ordered, and so indeed their union is well-ordered; the set of enumerations for each one is *not* necessarily well-orderable (since it has cardinality continuum), and in order to prove that the countable union of countable sets is countable, you have to choose an enumeration and not just a well-ordering.

Comment: You mean $\bigcup X$ is countable and it is contained in another countable ordinal, right? I have thought about that, but I have no idea about showing the existence of such countable ordinal containing $\bigcup X$..

Comment: @Ifexists: No, $\bigcup X$ ***is*** an ordinal, and assuming the axiom of choice, it's also countable. Just show that $\bigcup X$ satisfies the definition of an ordinal (whichever definition you have), and show that if $\beta$ is an upper bound for $X$, then $\bigcup X\leq\beta$ to conclude that this is the supremum.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.